# API docs getFeaturesInExtent

Tags: openlayers

I'm having difficulties to understand the API docs for `getFeaturesInExtent`:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#getFeaturesInExtent

> Get all features in the provided extent. Note that this **returns an array of all features intersecting the given extent** in random order (**so it may include features whose geometries do not intersect the extent**).

How is it possible that the returned array may include features whose geometries do not intersect the extent, if `getFeaturesInExtent` returns an array of all features intersecting the given extent?

Comment: Presumably means the feature's (rectangular) bounding box intersecting the extent (as in forEachFeatureInExtent), and not necessarily its geometry (as in forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent).  If you are only interested in geometries you could build your own array by calling forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a possible explanation. I'll try it out.

Comment: this makes little sense...it definitely returns features outside the extent, seems very strangely worded